# Talend: Insert CSV data into parent and child table

Tags: talend

I have a CSV file containing users data that I want to insert into two tables in a MySQL database. The file format is as follows:

[image]

I want to insert into a table called users so the result would be:

[image]

And another child table having the foreign key called user options:

[image]

So, each row should be inserted once in users table and then insert each of its options (first name/last name and other names which is type 1 or city/country which is type 2) split into users options table.

I am using Talend Data Integration Studio to create such a job.

I would appreciate a step-by-step solution as I am still a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**I need to insert the foreign key of the user options table as the primary key of the row in the users table which is set to be auto incremented.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution.
[image]
tMap_1 basically duplicates the data in 3 outputs. The first goes to users table where we insert the external_id, first_name, last_name and age. The id of the table is auto incremented, so it doesn't need to be inserted here.
[image]
The 2nd output sets the type to 1, and gets the id and other_names; the 3rd output set the type to 2 and gets the id and locations.
tNormalize_1 normalizes the data in other names since it contains a list of names separated by ";".
[image]

tExtractDelimitedFields_1 extracts the first name and last name from the normalized data.
[image]
[image]

tNormalize_2 and tExtractDelimitedFields_2 do the same thing with the locations data.
Here are the results:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try it out and mark your answer. However, I misinterpreted one thing. The ``user_id`` as the foreign key should be the primary auto incremented key of the users table. How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: What you can do is insert all the data in users table (1st output of my tMap) then in a 2nd subjob, join your file data with the users table on the external_id column, and retrieve the id which was created when you inserted the data, and use that instead in my solution

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I'd really appreciate it if you add this to the answer please.